# How to check through an entire list in Python for a condition fulfillment

Tags: list, python-3.x, loops

So I'm trying to make a single line to check if a single element in Python list fits the criteria, but my current code will keep the loop going even if it hits a "True" -mark and thus only the last element counts for the check:

```
if [[CheckStatus(value, outsidevalue)] for value in valuelist] is True:
    magic
```

(CheckStatus returns either True or False for every single value compared to outsidevalue and is supposed to accept is as true if a single value returns True)

Comment: See `all` and `any` built-in functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that will always be false:

```
if [[CheckStatus(value, outsidevalue)] for value in valuelist] is True:
```

because you're comparing a `list` with a `boolean`.

What you want is `any`:

```
if any(CheckStatus(value, outsidevalue) for value in valuelist):
```

`any` iterates on the generator comprehension, calling your function on all elements until `True` is found (note that the inside square brackets have been removed, and we don't need to create a list comprehension, just a generator comprehension, which is faster)